# I need a suitable verb for research

Tags: research

I want to  list some researches done by some people on a specific topic.can I say : "a research was conducted by Smith et al.......
what verbs are suitable for research?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. There’s also [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) where you might find some useful information and similar questions. The word "research" is normally considered uncountable these days, so "a research" and "researches" indicate that English is a second language to you. It is better to say "research conducted by Smith et al", but in place of "conducted" you could also say "done" or simply cite: "In (1) Smith et al examined/analysed/reviewed....".

Comment: @Pam What if the OP is not a native speaker?

Comment: @Kris, that's ok. It's just a quick search showed me that use of research as a countable noun (i.e. researches) is a controversial issue, and I'm reluctant to say if it's right or wrong. "Researches" to me (native speaker) is a verb: "He researches the past in preparation for the test". Used as a countable noun implies non-native speakers. Whether this is good or bad, I don't know, that's a different question. If I saw this ("some researches"), I'd be aware that the rest of the paper may contain non-standard (for me) word usage.

Comment: @Pam "You can refer to the **research** that someone is doing as their **research** or their **researches**. You normally only use **researches** after a possessive form such as **my**, **his**, or **Gordon's**." Collins COBUILD English Usage cited in https://www.thefreedictionary.com/research See also:  "‘he prefaces his study with a useful summary of his own researches’" https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/research *n.* "2. a particular instance or piece of research." Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary cited in https://www.thefreedictionary.com/research

Comment: Thanks @Kris. It looks like a similar use to people/peoples. I note that the [Collins COBUILD English Usage reference](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/research) also includes the advice "**Don't talk about 'a research'.**". I might try to formulate my own question on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "A research was conducted by …" does not use *research*  as a verb; it's a noun there.
2. Try ***study*** instead where you refer to individual cases:

   > "A **study** was conducted by …"
3. As for the verb, use *research* or *study* the same way as above.

HTH.